# What will be the most descriptive name for my method that returns a list of chess pieces attacking a square

Tags: java, oop, naming-conventions, chess

**Edit:** 
*Once again, thanks to those who commented and answered. Agreed, not the best question in the world, but I needed a little push to get past this obstacle in my mind. What I have taken with me in particular is that the return type is an important part of the method signature.*

One of the important aspects of clean coding is picking good names for your classes, variables and methods.

Following what I have read in literature and online, I would try and pick names that are, firstly, as descriptive (and therefore unambiguous) as possible, and secondly, as concise as possible.

I am for my own amusement and learning writing a chess game in java, and I have stumbled upon a method that I simply can't figure out how to name in a satisfactory way. The method lives on my `ISquare` interface and is intended to bring me back a list of pieces that are currently attacking that square.

To be fully descriptive the name should indicate that the method returns a collection of pieces, arguably even a list, and that the pieces are attacking this square instance. One could argue that the latter is implied by where the method lives, but I'm not too sure about that.

The most descriptive name I can think of is probably in violation of every single other naming convention, and obviously won't do:

```
List<IPiece> giveMeTheListOfPiecesThatThisSquareIsUnderAttackBy();
```

These two alternatives show that the method relates to the current instance, but seem to hint that the result is of a boolean nature:

```
List<IPiece> isUnderAttackByPieces();
List<IPiece> underAttackByPieces();
```

The next one is descriptive about the return type, but not explicit about what the pieces are attacking:

```
List<IPiece> getAttackingPieces();
```

This one might satisfy my criteria, but intuitively I would say that using the words "This" and "Square" doesn't look very good:

```
List<IPiece> piecesAttackingThisSquare();
```

Currently I have settled with `underAttackByPieces()`, but as described above that doesn't quite nail it.

Any help you can offer will be most appreciated!

Comment: how about getThreats()? seriously though, youre putting too much thought into this

Comment: `"the name should indicate that the method returns a collection of pieces"` - why? I'd probably go with `getAttackingPieces` or simply `getAttackers`. Also, I'm questioning your design, why do you have a `ISquare` interface, and not simply put everything in the `Board`?

Comment: The returning datatype implies that a list of items will be returned.  Beyond that the name you choose is not too important as long as it relates to the question.  If it it's not clear enough, add some documentation.  You are over thinking this.

Comment: Remember that the whole method signature is important: not just the method name. "giveMeTheListOfPiecesThatThisSquareIsUnderAttackBy". "ListOfPieces" is taken care of by your return type (eg. List<Piece>). "ThisSquare" is taken care of by your argument to the method (Square square).

Comment: +1 to @Dukeling's `getAttackers()`. -10000 to every other commenter's "doesn't matter lol". Getting things right always matters. Hang your heads in shame.

Comment: @TomAnderson There's still a point where you've put far too much effort into choosing the perfect name for your method. Honestly, I think the OP should have stopped when they got to "getAttackingPieces()" - it's an instance method, so the fact it relates to the instance it's being called on is already implied.

Comment: @Dukeling I need squares in this implementation, because I want to model the relationship between a square and its neighbours, so that getting all available moves becomes less processing intensive. I welcome your scepticism, though!

Comment: Note that questions about naming convention and the like may be better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (at least so I think, I know it isn't really suited for SO).

Comment: I kinda understand why this was closed, so just want to take the opportunity to thank those who answered, your answers were actually very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would settle with `getAttackingPieces`. Since it's a method of `ISquare`, I think it is clear enough what is under attack. You can be more explicit in the method's Javadoc comment.